# Wordpress rewrite with php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is possible change this url

```
www.12345.com/?s=&cp_state=city
```

to this?

```
www.12345.com/city
```

Already try with htaccess but in wordpress it doesen't work

Hi have this code. Is possible change it to have a url like this www.12345.com/city?

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'search_url_rewrite_rule');
function search_url_rewrite_rule() {
global $wp_rewrite;

if ( is_search() && isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    $s = str_replace( array( ' ', '%20' ), '+', get_query_var( 's' ) );
    wp_redirect( home_url( $wp_rewrite->search_base . '/' . remove_accents (   $s ) ) );
    exit();
}
}

add_action('init','change_search_permalinks');
function change_search_permalinks( ) {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->search_base = 'search';
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite wordpress url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987978/rewrite-wordpress-url)

Answer (score 0):

In php level it is not good idea
You can use url shortlink in admin area of wordpress.